# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'toLowerCase'

Tags: python

I am writing a program that asks you to enter  5 words (one at a time) and then prints them out in reverse order. (I am using Python 3.3.2)
Here is what it should look like:
http://s11.postimg.org/rayd8m3oj/Untitled.png

But instead it gives me this:

http://s10.postimg.org/c1p590vex/example.png

Here is my code:

```
fifth_word = input("Please enter your 1st word: ")
fifth_word = fifth_word.toLowerCase
fourth_word = input("Please enter your 2nd word: ")
fourth_word = fourth_word.toLowerCase
third_word = input("Please enter your 3rd word: ")
third_word = third_word.toLowerCase
second_word = input("Please enter your 4th word: ")
second_word = second_word.toLowerCase()
first_word = input("Please enter your 5th word: ")
first_word = first_word.capitalize()
print("The sentence is: " + first_word + second_word + third_word + fourth_word + fifth_word)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Python [`str`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str) class does not contain a method named `toLowerCase`. The method that you are looking for is [`lower`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower).

When you are faced with such an error message, the first thing you should do is to see what the class in question can do.

```
>>> s = 'some string'
>>> dir(s)
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__'
, '__getitem__', '__getnewargs__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mod__', '__mul_
_', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__'
, '__subclasshook__', 'capitalize', 'casefold', 'center', 'count', 'encode', 'endswith', 'expandtabs', 'find', 'format', 'format_m
ap', 'index', 'isalnum', 'isalpha', 'isdecimal', 'isdigit', 'isidentifier', 'islower', 'isnumeric', 'isprintable', 'isspace', 'ist
itle', 'isupper', 'join', 'ljust', 'lower', 'lstrip', 'maketrans', 'partition', 'replace', 'rfind', 'rindex', 'rjust', 'rpartition
', 'rsplit', 'rstrip', 'split', 'splitlines', 'startswith', 'strip', 'swapcase', 'title', 'translate', 'upper', 'zfill']
```

As you can see, `toLowerCase` is not here. But you can also see `lower` which should steer you in the right direction. And don't be afraid to look in the documentation which is invariably of excellent quality.

Comment: That is useful - thanks! How did you get all those string values?

Comment: The code in my answer came from the interactive prompt. Start one up yourself, and type in exactly what I did. And what I did was use the most useful `dir()` function: http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#dir

Comment: You may also find `help(s)` to be as useful as `dir`.

Answer (score 4):

Use `str.lower()` instead.

```
fifth_word = input("Please enter your 1st word: ")
fifth_word = fifth_word.lower()
fourth_word = input("Please enter your 2nd word: ")
fourth_word = fourth_word.lower()
third_word = input("Please enter your 3rd word: ")
third_word = third_word.lower()
second_word = input("Please enter your 4th word: ")
second_word = second_word.lower()
first_word = input("Please enter your 5th word: ")
first_word = first_word.capitalize()
print("The sentence is: " + first_word + second_word + third_word + fourth_word + fifth_word)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works now. I'll add some spaces between the words so that it becomes a sentence